# как вернуть код не аутентифицирован по api виде Json Passport Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Passport все работает

возник вопрос в том что когда токен действительный все ок

но когда токен не верен он возвращает

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [login] not defined. in file /home/prof/calendar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php on line 444
```

//так как по умолчанию

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login'); //он ссылается на этот маршрут но запрос то по api нужно вернуть ответ в виде Json как тут быть?
        }
    }
}

//Вот ->middleware('auth:api') это Passport quard
Route::prefix('calendars')->middleware('auth:api')->group(function (){
        Route::apiResource('calendars', CalendarController::class)->except([
            'create', 'edit'
        ]);
    });
```

Comment: Вы не отправляете заголовок `Accept: application/json`, соответственно, редиректитесь на url. Если Вы будете обращаться правильно - будет приходить ответ в виде json.

Comment: #Vladimir Gonchar
Точно,  спасибо